# Perl not reading file when passed '+>>'

Tags: perl

I am trying to put the contents of a file into an array for grepping purposes but for some reason it is failing to do so when I pass the '+>>' argument. However when I open two separate file handles to the same file with different arguments it works.

This works:

```
open( FILEHANDLE, '<', $file ) or $file_not_found = 1;
open( APPENDFH, '>>', $file );
my @file_list = <FILEHANDLE>;
print("This is my file list @file_list \n");
```

Prints:

```
This is my file list 2015-11-06 11:17:57Example
```

This does not:

```
open( FILEHANDLE, '+>>', $file ) or $file_not_found = 1;
my @file_list = <FILEHANDLE>;
print("This is my file list @file_list \n");
```

Prints:

```
This is my file list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+>>` opens the file at the end. You need to rewind to the beginning to read from it:

```
seek FILEHANDLE, 0, 0;
```

But you can then open the file directly with `+<`.

Answer (score 4):

`>>` and `+>>` open the file for append (`O_APPEND`), which places the file cursor at the end of the file. You could move the file pointer using `seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET)`, or you could open the file using `+<`.